# sending information and getting response in android

Tags: android

In my app i need something like that.In my app a user can easily be a member  by signing up.Now when a user become a member then he can communicate with other members.Suppose a want to send a message(same message) to all users, same location as he is.Or it may be something like that a user want to send a message(same message) to another 5 users whom he knows.
How can i do that.
I googled may times.I thought web-service can do that job.But i didn't right way to do that.
Can anyone how can i do that with references ???

Comment: You cant Do that with Preferences As Preferences are Local.U can use any web Service using PHP or .Net.

Comment: How can i interact with php as web to android ??@geet

Comment: U can store your data in webserver using PHP & u need to create API for Android in PHP.Then u can call these Api from Android Side to get User's info or sending messages.

Comment: Can you suggest me some good reference to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer following:

Simple PHP With MySQl(To get basics, No Interaction with Android)

http://davidwalsh.name/web-service-php-mysql-xml-json

One Demo:(Interaction with Android)

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/267023/Send-and-receive-json-between-android-and-php

Good Tutorial:(Interaction with Android)

part1-http://guruparang.blogspot.in/2012/11/connect-android-and-mysql-via-php.html

part2-http://guruparang.blogspot.in/2012/12/connect-android-and-mysql-via-php.html

Best Tutorial (Here u can get All the idea):

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/

Answer (score 0):

Use [parse.com](http://parse.com)

Download the sample app. The sample app works both locally in Android and on the server-side. It does the hardest part for you.

Just modify it to make it fit your needs.